# Python: Convert a json string that encodes an hexadecimal in an array of bytes

Tags: python, arrays, hex

I have a json with data="90ab"

```
unpack = json.loads(content)
data = unpack['data']
data_byte=bytearray.fromhex(data)
```

I want data_byte to be an array of bytes [byte1 byte2], with byte1=0x90, and byte2=0xab
I need help, because what I tried doesn't seem to work
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Convert a bytes array into JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059654/python-convert-a-bytes-array-into-json-format)

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on python version, so the way to decode hex data may vary:

```
data="90ab"
```

## Since Python 2.7 and 3.0:

```
bytearray.fromhex(data)
```

## Python 2.6 and before:

```
data.decode("hex")
```