# Invert Nested Dictionary of Unknown Depth

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to get a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{1:{2:{3:{4:'foo'}}}}
```

to look like this:

```
'foo': [1,2,3,4]
```

The dictionary is nested to an unknown depth. This is definitely testing my recursion knowledge.

So far I have this. I think this works. However, I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this:

```
def denest(nested_dict):
    denested_dict = {}
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sub_dict = denest(v)
            for t, s in sub_dict.items():
                sub_dict[t] +=[k]
            denested_dict.update(sub_dict)
        else:
            denested_dict[v] = [k]

    return denested_dict
```

Comment: What if there was an additional key in one of the nested dictionaries? Do you want multiple lists linked to each path?

Comment: You may find my [`show_indices`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414034/4014959) helpful when dealing with nested data structures like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of the keys that have been seen:

```
def build_new(_d, seen = []):
  [[a, b]] = _d.items()
  return {b:seen+[a]} if not isinstance(b, dict) else build_new(b, seen+[a])

print(build_new({1:{2:{3:{4:'foo'}}}}))
```

Output:

```
{'foo': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

However, the above solution will only work when each dictionary only has one key. To find all paths generically, use `yield`:

```
def all_paths(d, seen = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if not isinstance(b, dict):
      yield {b:seen+[a]}
    else:
      yield from all_paths(b, seen+[a])

d = {1:{2:{3:'bar', 4:'foo', 5:{6:'stuff'}}}}
print(list(all_paths(d)))
```

Output:

```
[{'bar': [1, 2, 3]}, {'foo': [1, 2, 4]}, {'stuff': [1, 2, 5, 6]}]
```

Comment: @eljusticiero67 Do not call these functions on more than one dict. They won't work correctly because `seen` is a mutable default argument, so it acts as a cache, which you don't want here.

Comment: I should mention that you can get around that problem by simply passing an empty list as the `seen` arg. For more info on this topic, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument