# parse JSON with unknown keys and types [python]

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to read any json response I get from AWS APIs. For example, ec2_client. describe_network_interfaces().
Using some help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414034/17750094, I managed to create a dictionary with all the key value pairs on all levels. But is there a better way to do this?

my code so far:

```
def read_dict(dato):
    key_value = {}
    for keys, v in show_indices(dato, []):
        key = ".".join(map(str, keys))
        key_value.update({str(key): v})
    return key_value


def show_indices(dato, indices):
    for k, v in dato.items() if isinstance(dato, dict) else enumerate(dato):
        if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
            yield from show_indices(v, indices + [k])
        else:
            yield indices + [k], v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    data = ec2.describe_network_interfaces()

    list_of_dicts = []

    for d in data:
        list_of_dicts.append(read_dict(d))
```

json Data:

```
data = [
   {
      "Attachment":{
         "AttachTime":datetime.datetime(2023,3,2,1,2,2,"tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "AttachmentId":"eni-attach-123",
         "DeleteOnTermination":false,
         "DeviceIndex":1,
         "NetworkCardIndex":0,
         "InstanceOwnerId":"123",
         "Status":"attached"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone":"us-east-5g",
      "Description":"AWS network interface",
      "Groups":[
         {
            "GroupName":"d-123",
            "GroupId":"sg-123"
         }
      ],
      "InterfaceType":"interface",
      "Ipv6Addresses":[
         
      ],
      "MacAddress":"c5:d5:ad:3b:f5:1d",
      "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-123",
      "OwnerId":"123",
      "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "PrivateIpAddresses":[
         {
            "Primary":true,
            "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1"
         }
      ],
      "RequesterId":"123",
      "RequesterManaged":true,
      "SourceDestCheck":true,
      "Status":"in-use",
      "SubnetId":"subnet-123",
      "TagSet":[
         
      ],
      "VpcId":"vpc-123"
   },
   {
      "Attachment":{
         "AttachTime":datetime.datetime(2023,3,2,1,2,2,"tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "AttachmentId":"eni-attach-123",
         "DeleteOnTermination":false,
         "DeviceIndex":1,
         "NetworkCardIndex":0,
         "InstanceOwnerId":"123",
         "Status":"attached"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone":"us-east-1f",
      "Description":"AWS network interface",
      "Groups":[
         {
            "GroupName":"d-123",
            "GroupId":"sg-123"
         }
      ],
      "InterfaceType":"interface",
      "Ipv6Addresses":[
         
      ],
      "MacAddress":"25:fd:ff:e2:35:c2",
      "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-123",
      "OwnerId":"123",
      "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "PrivateIpAddresses":[
         {
            "Primary":true,
            "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1"
         }
      ],
      "RequesterId":"123",
      "RequesterManaged":true,
      "SourceDestCheck":true,
      "Status":"in-use",
      "SubnetId":"subnet-123",
      "TagSet":[
         
      ],
      "VpcId":"vpc-123"
   }
]
```

Output as a list of dicts:

```
[
   {
      "Attachment.AttachTime":datetime(2023,3,2,1,2,2,"tzinfo=tzutc())",
      "Attachment.AttachmentId":"eni-attach-123",
      "Attachment.DeleteOnTermination":false,
      "Attachment.DeviceIndex":1,
      "Attachment.NetworkCardIndex":0,
      "Attachment.InstanceOwnerId":"123",
      "Attachment.Status":"attached",
      "AvailabilityZone":"us-east-5g",
      "Description":"AWS network interface",
      "Groups.0.GroupName":"d-123",
      "Groups.0.GroupId":"sg-123",
      "InterfaceType":"interface",
      "MacAddress":"c5:d5:ad:3b:f5:1d",
      "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-123",
      "OwnerId":"123",
      "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "PrivateIpAddresses.0.Primary":true,
      "PrivateIpAddresses.0.PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "RequesterId":"123",
      "RequesterManaged":true,
      "SourceDestCheck":true,
      "Status":"in-use",
      "SubnetId":"subnet-123",
      "VpcId":"vpc-123"
   },
   {
      "Attachment.AttachTime":datetime.datetime(2023,3,2,1,2,2,"tzinfo=tzutc())",
      "Attachment.AttachmentId":"eni-attach-123",
      "Attachment.DeleteOnTermination":false,
      "Attachment.DeviceIndex":1,
      "Attachment.NetworkCardIndex":0,
      "Attachment.InstanceOwnerId":"123",
      "Attachment.Status":"attached",
      "AvailabilityZone":"us-east-1f",
      "Description":"AWS network interface",
      "Groups.0.GroupName":"d-123",
      "Groups.0.GroupId":"sg-123",
      "InterfaceType":"interface",
      "MacAddress":"25:fd:ff:e2:35:c2",
      "NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-123",
      "OwnerId":"123",
      "PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "PrivateIpAddresses.0.Primary":true,
      "PrivateIpAddresses.0.PrivateIpAddress":"1.1.1.1",
      "RequesterId":"123",
      "RequesterManaged":true,
      "SourceDestCheck":true,
      "Status":"in-use",
      "SubnetId":"subnet-123",
      "VpcId":"vpc-123"
   }
]
```

The output is writen to a csv file.

But is there a better way to do this?
I would prefer for example not to keep all keys for each level. Not to keep list indexes.

Instead of

```
"Groups.0.GroupName":"d-123",
```

I want

```
"GroupName":"d-123",
```

Comment: But what if you had something like `{ "Product" : { "Name" : "XYZ" }, "Customer" : { "Name" : "PQR" } }`?

Comment: Or to use your example, if there was more than one `Group` in `Groups`, you'd have multiple `GroupName` keys

Comment: @Nick Correct! I need the indexes. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: is `data` meant to be a json string or a python dict?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want to solve it using scratch logic but if you just want to solve the problem then there is a python package which is far better. You can visit the package here
https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/